# Formula Field to calculate # of months on contract

Tags: formula-field, contracts

I have two custom date fields on the contract object called contract start date and contract end date that are both just date fields.

How would I write a custom formula field that looks at both and tells me the number of months for the contract?

Tried, (MONTH(EndDate)-MONTH(StartDate))/30 so far

and then (EndDate - StartDate)/30 which works sometimes but not others

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Sure  I tried (MONTH(EndDate)-MONTH(StartDate))/30  but I realize now that definitely wont work

Comment: Sorry, updated my comment

Comment: Did you try it? https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h22TAAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this formula and works fine

```
(
    ( (YEAR(End_Date__c ) - YEAR(Start_Date__c ) - 1) *12 ) 
    + (12 - MONTH(Start_Date__c ) +1)
    + MONTH(End_Date__c )
    - 1 
    + IF(DAY(End_Date__c ) > DAY(Start_Date__c ),1,0)
)
```

you can do a -1 if you will not consider the first month = 1